# Что более выгодно с точки зрения памяти и времени выполнения? Throws or try/catch

Tags: java, try-catch

Что более выгодно с точки зрения памяти и времени выполнения? Пробросить исключение в сигнатуру метода или обработать его конкретно.
Задали такой вопрос на собеседовании (junior). Перерыл уже весь гугл, но так и не смог найти конкретное объяснение.

Comment: А взять да померить самому? И нам бы рассказали заодним. У меня есть предположение, но это только предположение.

Comment: Пробросить исключение быстрее, нежели обрабатывать его напрямую в коде. Насколько быстрее непонятно, но быстрее.